# Making a square wave generator using basic components

Tags: oscillator

I know how to make a square wave generator using 2 resistors, a capacitor and a ne555 ic. But is to also possible to make a semi-good square wave generator using just a couple transistors, resistors and capacitors? If so how?

Comment: You might be better asking on a MacGyver forum...

Comment: Google "astable multivibrator"

Comment: I am intrigued by the "semi-good" term...

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm guessing only half of it would be square...

Comment: @trevor, the circuit I find when googling astable multivibrator generates a sawtooth wave, not a square wave.

Comment: https://electrosome.com/astable-multivibrator-transistors/

Comment: How about a double plus good square wave?

Comment: @uint128_t okay, i get my way of decribing a wave that only kind of needs to resemble a square wave with a reasonable margin for error is apparently very funny. But i'm new to electronics and everybody has to learn, how would you describe a not at all perfect but still kinda square-ish square wave?

Comment: You would describe the tolerances associated with the square wave parameters, as derived from your requirements: rise/fall time, high/low voltage, etc. Because you didn't specify what the square wave will be driving, we have no idea how square it needs to be.

Comment: I guess i have a lot of reading to do about what all those things mean, i would appreciate it if you guys would be more helpful and less sarcastic though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to make a square wave generator with two transistors as the active components.

Whether the result is "semi-good" or meets any other nebulous metric is impossible to say since these metrics aren't defined.  We do engineering here, so discussion of such things are pointless, and off topic anyway.

Comment: I guess i misphrased my question, please read last three words.

Comment: @DutChen18 As already stated Google "astable multivibrator"!  First link.

Comment: @Dut: You added those after the fact.  I answer the question you originally ask, as written at the time I answered it.

Comment: OlinLathrop i was asking if you could update your answer, StainlessSteelRat, in the current state of this answer it doesn't answer my question as i meant to ask it, i was asking him to update his answer so i can mark it as solved.

Comment: @Dut: If you want a answer to a totally different question than what was originally asked, as seems to be the case here, you should ask a new question on this SE site.  It's not appropriate to grossly change a question after it was posted, and especially after it has been answered.

Comment: I didn't change my question, i added clarification. Because apparently it wasn't obvious that i actually wanted an example instead of just knowing wheter it was possible.